# Set page as parent of custom post type in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how I can set a custom post type page to be a child of a WordPress page.

For example, I have created a custom post type named Products, to create a page for each product.

On my site however, the hierarchy should be like:

```
Homepage (Wordpress pages)
-Products List Page (Wordpress pages)
--Product detail page (Custom Posts Type 'Products')
```

The problem is, because all my Product detail pages are CPT, I can't tell them that they are child of `Product List Page` which is a normal WordPress page.

Does anybody have a solution for this problem?

Comment: I'm wondering why the CPT needs to be a child of the regular page. As far as I can tell, you don't need that to make this work.

Comment: It need to be a child page... because if not all my breacrumb and navigation will be broken?

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/216712/229903), which uses Wordpress' built-in hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

I answered a similar question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/81715). In your function that registers the product post type, set the rewrite arg to something like:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'product-list/product'),
```

In this example, `product-list` is the slug of the page. Then, set `has_archive` to `false`:

```
'has_archive' => false
```

Visit the Permalinks settings page in your admin after you made the changes to flush the rewrite rules.

Note that this will not make your product detail pages actual child pages. But the URL structure will at least create the illusion that they are.

Comment: I was aware of this trick, but i was wondering if there was any other solution that was actually setting the CTF as a child

Comment: You could hook into `save_post` and set the page ID as `post_parent` but I'm not sure if that would be useful